# Update the config file of minion with the IP Address of one minion

Tags: salt-stack, configurationmanager

First of all I am pretty new to salt so pardon me if its a trivial question.

I have a salt-master and 3 salt-minions(1 license-minion, 2 app-minion) running in my setup .
The requirement  have is to update the configuration files in the 2 app-minions with the IP Address of the license-minion.

I know that :

`sudo salt 'license-minion' network.ip_addrs`

will return the IP Address , but how do I apply it to the app-minions.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It depends on which kind of configuration file. In general you can achieve your requirement with the state module [file.managed](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.managed). Have a look at the [salt formulas](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/salt-formula). Maybe the service which you would like to configure is already there.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [Salt Mine](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/3002/topics/mine/index.html). Salt master can retrieve required information from the minions using `mine_functions`. Other minions can then query this "mine" data. `mine_functions` can be added in the minion's configuration file or in (minion's) pillar.

Example minion pillar file `license-minion.sls`:

```yaml
mine_functions:
  network.ip_addrs:
    - interface: ens192
```

Pillar refresh, and check if the newly added `mine_functions` shows up:

```
salt '*' saltutil.refresh_pillar
salt '*' pillar.items
```

Now we can get the IP address of the license-minion in app-minion by running the `mine.get` function from the [mine module](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/3002/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.mine.html).

```
salt 'app-minion1' mine.get license-minion network.ip_addrs
```

Gives

```
app-minion1:
    ----------
    license-minion:
        - 1.2.3.4
```

The same function can be invoked from template files as:

```
{% set lm_data = salt['mine.get']('license-minion', 'network.ip_addrs') | dictsort() %}
```

The documentation has some examples on how this information can be used in templates.